# Check the Fourier transform for a function: $F[f]=?,f(x)=xe^{-\alpha|x|}$

Tags: fourier-transform

We have a function to transform (get $F[f(x)]$):

> $$f(x)=xe^{-\alpha|x|}$$

Using this formula ([v.p. meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value)):

$$F[f(y)]=v.p.\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{f(t)e^{-ity}dt}$$

In my school, I went to the board and solved this. But now I tried to solve it again, and got other answer (other sign).

My way:

$$F[f(y)]=
\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{0}{(f(t)e^{-ity}dt)}+\int_{0}^{+\infty}{(f(t)e^{-ity}dt)}\right)=
\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}(\int_{-\infty}^{0}{(te^{\alpha t}e^{-ity}dt)}+\int_{0}^{+\infty}{(te^{-\alpha t}e^{-ity}dt)})=
\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}(\int_{-\infty}^{0}{(te^{\alpha t-ity}dt)}+\int_{0}^{+\infty}{(te^{-\alpha t-ity}dt)})
$$

Replace with: ($\alpha t-ity=t\beta$) and ($-\alpha t-ity=t\gamma$) and continue:

$$F[f(y)]=
\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}(\int_{-\infty}^{0}{(te^{t\beta}dt)}+\int_{0}^{+\infty}{(te^{t\gamma}dt)})
$$

And I just computed this two integrals using Wolframalpha:

$$F[f(y)]=
\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}(-\frac1{\beta^2}+\frac1{\gamma^2})
$$

Now we should just recover replaced, simplify, and result will be like:

> $$F[f(y)]=-\frac{4\alpha i y}{\sqrt{2\pi}(\alpha^2+y^2)^2}$$

Is it correct?

Comment: Use `\left(` and `\right)` for larger parentheses.  What does "v.p." stand for?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I would guess its the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value)

Comment: @Egor Wolfram has the ability to compute Fourier transforms. [It says](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=fourier+transform+of+x+exp%28-k+%7Cx%7C%29) you are missing a sign. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GAjL.png)

Comment: Oh, I misread your final answer. The minus sign is correct. Sorry!

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yes, thank you, it was my fault that I was not giving v.p. meaning. And yes, you have presented true meaning of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Result is correct (and there is no need for the principal value as the integrand is continuous and integrable). Wolfram [can check](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=fourier%20transform%20of%20x%20exp%28-k%20%7Cx%7C%29) 1D Fourier transforms ([pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GAjL.png)).
$\renewcommand{\xi}y$

Another way to get the result by hand. [Perhaps](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/353833/80734) you know the result ($\mathcal Ff(\xi):=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-ix\xi}dx) $
$$ F_1(\xi):= \mathcal F(\exp(-|x|))(\xi)=\frac2{\xi^2+1}$$
Scaling:
$$ F_\alpha(\xi):=\mathcal F(\exp(-\alpha|x|)(\xi)=\frac1\alpha F_1\left(\frac\xi \alpha\right) = \frac{2\alpha}{\xi^2+\alpha^2}$$
Since $$\mathcal F (-ixf) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) (\partial_\xi e^{-ix\xi}) dx = \partial_\xi \mathcal F(f)(\xi) $$
we have $$ \mathcal F(x\exp(-\alpha|x|))(\xi)= i\partial_\xi F_\alpha(\xi) = i \cdot 2k \cdot \frac1{(\xi^2+\alpha^2)^2}\cdot (-1) \cdot 2\xi = \frac{-4i\alpha\xi}{(\xi^2+\alpha^2)^2}$$

which is your answer (up to convention for defining $\mathcal F$)

Comment: Everything is clear, but I think that renaming the values makes understanding more difficult. In case, we cannot compare the result sign-by-sign

Comment: Yes, sorry. I just used the notation that I am familliar with to minimise errors. I have changed it!